# How to link data from .csv to my turtles?

Tags: netlogo

In a .csv file I have two columns, age and fertility rates, of course representing fertility rates by age. How can I use the information in the .csv file to create the variable "fertility-rate" of each turtle based on their age?

Probably (and hopefully) the answer is really trivial, I'm still quite new to NetLogo, thank you in advance for the answers.

I tried importing the data and using it as a table, but I cannot figure out what to do from that point forward.

```
extensions [csv]

globals [mortality-table]

to setup
  set mortality-table csv:from-file "path-to-the-file"
end
```

Of course one answer would be simply manually introducing the fertility rates for each age, but I'm sure that a less tedious answer should exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are close... (please be aware that I did not test this code).

You can make a table directly from a list using table:from-list, and you can make that list from your CSV file using csv:from-file. Do it all at once using:

```
set mortality-table table:from-list (csv:from-file "path-to-file")
```

(but perhaps you mean "fertility-table"?)

Then you will need to tell each turtle to get its fertility rate:

```
ask turtles
[ set fertility-rate table:get fertility-table my-age ]
```

So, your idea was very good; you just need to read the user manual for the table extension carefully to see exactly how to do it.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I couldn't make your code work for some reason, although it was probably a mistake on my part, I posted the solution I came up with thanks to part of your code, although it's not that pretty. Thank you so much anyway for taking your time to help me, I highly appreciate it¡

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a workaround which is as follows, thanking in big part to Steve Railsback, that may be helpful for someone in the future:

```
extensions [ table ]
globals [fertility-table] ;; We create the global table "fertility table" the left column is age 
                          ;; and the right column is fertility rate for that age

turtles-own [age fertility-rate ]


to setup
  clear-all
  setup-globals       
  create-turtles 200 [    setxy random-xcor random-ycor ;; We just create some turtles and spread them
    set age random 100                                  ;; with randome ages comprised from0 to 100
  carefully [ set fertility-rate table:get fertility-table age ] ;; We ask to link the age with the 
                                                                 ;; values in the fertility-table global
      [ set fertility-rate 0            ;; set a default value if the age is not present in the table
  ]]
  reset-ticks

end


to setup-globals
  ;; First we configure the fertility global, to do so we create to "columns" fertility-list and age-fertility
  ;; I'ts not such a hustle to create this list if we are working on a wide-format spreadsheet, just copy and paste
  let fertility-list [0.001116649 0.002047191 0.003948731 0.006699896 0.010802369 0.013602084 0.016571724 0.01888594 0.021976955 0.025707211 0.029324184 0.033653224 0.038718604 0.045968734 0.052984205 0.060711743 0.066837131 0.070065704 0.071336095 0.07165167 0.068463555 0.0616261 0.053550621 0.044415135 0.034988348 0.025958053 0.018287157 0.011959477 0.007144938 0.004644614 0.002751165 0.001480774 0.000865808 0.000542141 0.000712066]
  let age-fertility [15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
  
  ;;  Now we just create a table from this lists using the primitive from-list and map
  set fertility-table table:from-list (map list age-fertility fertility-list)
  
end
```

It's not that pretty... but it works for now¡ I'm still getting started with the language in netlogo, so my apologies to my fellow more seasoned users for the multiple sins in my code